# Maximum immeasurable events in a probability space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm not at all aware of measure theory. But I came to know from probability theory that there may exists some events for uncountable sample spaces.

Is there any upperbound on number of such immeasurable events?

**Formally**

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space. Then $F\subseteq 2^\Omega$. I want to know whether there is any upper bound for $|2^\Omega - F|$.

Comment: What kind of upper bound are you looking for? Because, $\vert 2^\Omega \vert$ is a trivial upper bound. That said, unless you specify $F$, I believe that is the only upper bound you can have.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist means all events are immeasurable? How can it be if there are two measurable events we always have?

Comment: That also depends on $P$. If e.g. $P=\delta_{\omega_0}$ for some fixed $\omega_0\in\Omega$ (i.e. $P(A)=1$ of $\omega_0\in A$ and $P(A)=0$ otherwise) then for $F$ you can take the powerset of $\Omega$.

Comment: In general $|2^\Omega|$ is actually a tight bound for some examples. If for example $\Omega=\mathbb R$ and $F$ is countable then there is "equality"

Comment: Are you sure you are stating the question corretly. It makes more sense to ask for maximum of cardinality if $F$ itself.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Two sets can have the same cardinality even though one is strictly included in the other. Consider $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$. @hanugm

Comment: @KaboMurphy That might be a better question, but it's different from this one.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I agree. Your answer is correct for  the question OP asked. I had typed an answer for the other question and subsequently deleted it. Just wanted to check with OP which one was really intended.

Answer (score 1):

You do have the bound $$ \lvert 2^\Omega - F \rvert \le \lvert 2^\Omega\rvert. $$

Indeed, without saying more about what $F$ is, then this is the only upper bound you can have. To see this, note that we can choose $\Omega = \mathbb R$, $F = \{ \emptyset, \Omega \}$, so that $\lvert 2^\Omega - F \rvert = \lvert 2^\Omega\rvert$.